What is a `galley` in source2e?
More recent versions of source2e, refer to galley, without providing a definition, as to its meaning. I am aware of past efforts to restructure the ouput routine with xgalley, but at a stage it was mentioned that the LaTeX Team will not provide a replacement for the output routine. In TeX terminology what is a galley? Also is there intention to do major changes in the output routine?

@UlrichDiez Thanks, but I am looking for the Texspeak! Also a galley and a galley proof or 'proof'  are two different things. I like the German word Setzchiff!

@UlrichDiez  The closest thing that comes to mind is "current page", as defined in the output routine by Knuth.

yannisl: a galley is a the intermediate state of build a page prior to deciding where to cut it. As @UlrichDiez said, it is what Don calls the "current page" in the TeXbook

@FrankMittelbach  Thanks, although your concept is more like "current partial page". Are you planning to advance xgalley?

@yannisl this came up a few days ago in chat and, to paraphrase/summarise, the answer seems to be 'bits of it might get picked up at some point, but other bits are probably dead in the water'.

@FrankMittelbach I didn't say that... yannisl said that.
